# Problem with second monitor's resolution

Tags: drivers, nvidia, multiple-monitors, display, display-resolution

I know there are tons of post similar to this but I am unable to find a solution to my problem. I just made a clean install of Ubuntu 17.10 ( cause I mess things with my Nvidia drivers and I decided to start over ). I have two identical monitors 21.5' full HD which I use but the second one has a fixed resolution of 1024x768. I tried to use both Nvidia drivers or default drivers without any result. As you will see it can't detect my second display at all.

[image]

Both monitors are plugged into the same GPU which is Nvidia GTX 950. The GPU has one DisplayPort, one HDMI, and one DVI-I input.

- The primary display uses a VGA to HDMI cable ( from Monitor to GPU)
- The second uses a VGA to DVI-I ( using a VGA to DVI adapter )

Below there is some information which might help.

**xrand output :**

```
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 2944 x 1080, maximum 8192 x 8192
XWAYLAND0 connected 1920x1080+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 480mm x 270mm
   1920x1080     59.96*+
XWAYLAND1 connected 1024x768+1920+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 0mm x 0mm
   1024x768      59.92*+
```

**lshw -c video output :**

```
  *-display                 
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: GM206 [GeForce GTX 950]
       vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
       version: a1
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=nouveau latency=0
       resources: irq:123 memory:f6000000-f6ffffff memory:e0000000-efffffff memory:f0000000-f1ffffff ioport:e000(size=128) memory:c0000-dffff
```

My drivers :

[image]

**What I have already tried with failute :**

Using the information on the ubuntu [wiki](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/X/Config/Resolution#Adding%20undetected%20resolutions) I tried to set the desire resolution manually following the commands below :

```
~$ cvt 1920 1080
# 1920x1080 59.96 Hz (CVT 2.07M9) hsync: 67.16 kHz; pclk: 173.00 MHz
Modeline "1920x1080_60.00"  173.00  1920 2048 2248 2576  1080 1083 1088 1120 -hsync +vsync
~$ xrandr --newmode "1920x1080_60.00"  173.00  1920 2048 2248 2576  1080 1083 1088 1120 -hsync +vsync
~$ xrandr --addmode XWAYLAND1 "1920x1080_60.00"
~$ xrandr --output XWAYLAND1 --mode "1920x1080_60.00"
xrandr: Configure crtc 1 failed
```

In case I use the Nvidia binary drivers from the Additional Drivers menu and do the same commands I will get "X Error of failed request:  BadMatch (invalid parameter attributes).." error, I already test it before making a clean install.

I try to use Arandr software which someone suggests on similar posts but still getting the same error.

Sorry for the long post. I tried to give as much information as I could.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a lot of search, I found a workaround ( or fix if I may call it). Here are the steps I did to fix it.

1. I disabled the Nvidia drivers from Software & Updates -> Additional Drivers
2. Having two identical monitors ( same vendor etc ) I acquire EDID of the working monitor
3. I generated the X configuration file through Nvidia settings window
4. I manually modified the xorg.conf file (located at /etc/X11/xorg.conf) and on the "Screen" section I added the following option :
   `Option "CustomEDID" "CRT-0:/myfullPath/edid.bin` where 'CRT-0' is the previously name of my monitor assigned by the Nvidia and the edid.bin is the EDID file of the working monitor.
5. then I made a reboot and everything was working fine.

Answer (score 3):

After days of research, this is what works for me in Ubuntu and Pop OS.

Just go to `/etc/X11/xorg.conf`
Scroll down to `Device` Section and
add `Option "IgnoreEDIDChecksum" "DFP-1"` just **before EndSection**

So now my Device Section looks like this.

```
Section "Device"
    Identifier     "Device0"
    Driver         "nvidia"
    VendorName     "NVIDIA Corporation"
    BoardName      "GeForce GTX 1050 Ti"
    Option "IgnoreEDIDChecksum" "DFP-1"
EndSection
```

I hope this helps anyone looking to solve this. Just for info, I have dual monitors and they belong to different brands but are the same size and resolution.

P.S You could try changing `DFP-1` to `DFP-0` and restart to test changes

Answer (score 2):

I had similar problem and fixed it by simply not using the VGA to DP adapter. Problem disappeared as soon as used a DP cable.